# how can i access a shared view model from an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have an activity that has many fragments in it, and I want to share things using a shared view model between fragments, but when I initialize it the way I do in fragments it doesn't work, it shows an error, what is the correct way to access it if it is possible?

```
    val model : sharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

i have tried to do ViewModelProvider but didn't know how to do it properly cause I am coding using kotlin

Comment: "it shows an error" -- what is the error? In the activity, you declare it using `by viewModels()`. In the fragments, you declare it using `by activityViewModels()`.

Comment: omg, i am gonna face palm if that works, thats a bruh moment right there!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have multiple fragments in a common activity instance share a viewmodel, the fragments can use `by activityViewModels()` property delegate. This returns a viewmodel scoped to the activity.

If you *also* want the activity to work with this viewmodel, the activity would declare it using the simpler `by viewModels()` property delegate. They did not bother creating `activityViewModels()` for an activity, as it would just be the same as the simpler `viewModels()`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read [Share data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) documentation

Activity use `viewModels<T>()`

Fragments use `activityViewModels<T>()`